# MysqlDump in aws rds mysql is not working properly

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, backup

When I run simple command:

```
mysqldump -h <rds-endpoint> \
-u smg \
-p'<rdsPassword>' \
--port=<port> \
--routines \
--triggers \
--databases <db-name> > file-name.sql
```

It is executing and finishing without any error, but as result it makes backup for only 3 table. Remeaning tables become missing. How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: If you connect using the `mysql` command line client using that `smg` user as your login, can you `SHOW TABLES` and see the tables that are missing? Can you query those tables with `SELECT` while connected as the `smg` user?